# How to get search box in `CommandBar` after update to Fabric 6

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I've updated Fabric to version 6.6.1 and noticed that property `isSearchBoxVisible` is missing in `CommandBar` component.

How to substitute it? I widely use it in my app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onRender` property of `IContextualMenuItem` as far as I know. I use it to show a custom control in my CommandBar:

```
const items: IContextualMenuItem[] = [];

items.push({
    key: "ArchivedToggle",
    name: "Archived Toggle",
    onRender: this.renderArchivedToggle.bind(this),
});
```

In the render function:

```
<CommandBar
    className={styles.actionBar}
    items={[]}
    farItems={items}
/>
```

In the custom render function, you can basicly create whatever you want. In this case it's a Toggle, but you can replace this by a SearchBox as well ofcourse.

```
private renderArchivedToggle() {
    <Toggle
        defaultChecked={props.defaultChecked}
        label=""
        onText={(_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage === Language.DUTCH) ? "Archief" : "Archive"}
        offText={(_spPageContextInfo.currentLanguage === Language.DUTCH) ? "Archief" : "Archive"}
        onChanged={(value: boolean) => props.updateValueHandler(value)}
    />
}
```

Result:

[image]